# How is the characteristic impedance of a transmission line sensed according to this paper?

Tags: impedance

This paper proposes a method to sense the characteristic impedance of a transmission line.

How is it done? I don't understand the explanation given.

Does anyone understand it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you send a signal into a transmission line, the current initially drawn by the line depends only on the signal voltage and the line's impedance. The line initially appears like a resistor, with the value of its impedance. Regardless of whether the far end of the line is open circuit, short circuit, or terminated in some arbitrary component, the initial input current depends on the line impedance, until the reflection from the far end gets back with evidence of what's on the far end.

If we  make a potential divider between a source resistor and the line, then the impedance of the line can be calculated from the voltage division between the source resistor and the line.

If we sample quickly enough, before the reflection from the far end gets back, we measure only the effect of the line impedance, and not whatever is connected to the far end.

This is all mentioned in the text immediately after the yellow-highlighted section.

This is the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line) on tranmission lines which may offer some further insight into how they behave.

Answer (score 0):

The cable appears as \$Z_0=\sqrt {\dfrac{L}{C}}\$ with a shifted switched R for Rp and   a switched current source with a sample and hold.

\$R_1//R_t/R_p\$ is compared with \$R_1//Z_0//R_p\$ until they match to determine Zo before a reflection occurs.

A better way is to compare \$Z_0 = R_p\$ both biased to say 1V until the difference <0 to match, but fine-tuning Rp requires a fixed reference and a smaller variable. The Rp can be switched as fast as the comparator can settle then shifted again until threshold ~0 so no  S&H is needed. It would just stop the next increment and read the number of increments to read Rp = Zo.